Some calculus questions regarding a reinforcement learning paper
I have a question to this paper from Reinforcement Learning, but I figured I ask it here because it involves mostly calculus. I am a bit confused because of some derivations.
(1) In the following they define a gradient of the matrix. Is this gradient then a matrix itself?

(2) Now in the following I don't understand why $\nabla\pi'e=\nabla(\pi'e)$. In the next part I assume something like this is happening:$\nabla\pi'(I-P) - \nabla\pi'e= \nabla\pi'(I-P + \pi'e)=\pi'\nabla P$ although I am not sure why in the paper $\pi'$ and $e$ are swapped.

(3) Here I don't understand why we can assume $\lim_{t \to \infty} A^{t} = 0$ and why does $(I-A)^{-1}=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}A^{t}$ show that the inverse exists?


$
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
$If $p$ is a scalar function of $\theta \in \R^K$ then $\nabla p$ is a vector (known as the gradient). Since $P$ is a matrix with elements $p_{ij}$ which are scalar functions of $\theta$, $\nabla P$ is a third-order tensor (an element of $\nabla P$ is described by three indices $i,j,k$).
$\pi' e$ is the inner (dot) product of a vector $\pi$ whose elements are functions of $\theta$ and $e=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots 1 \end{pmatrix}'$. So $\nabla (\pi'e)=(\nabla \pi')e$ or using the convention of the authors ($\nabla$ takes precedence over all other operations) $\nabla \pi'e$.
Starting from the balance equation
\begin{equation}
\pi'(\theta)P(\theta) = \pi'(\theta) \tag{12}
\end{equation}
apply $\nabla$ to get,
$$
\nabla\pi'P + \pi' \nabla P= \nabla \pi'  
$$
Since $\nabla \pi'=\nabla \pi'I$ we can rewrite the last equation as
$$
\nabla \pi' (I-P)= \pi' \nabla P \tag{15}
$$
$e\pi'$ is the outer-product of these two vectors. Each row has elements equal to $\pi(\theta,1),\ldots,\pi(\theta,n)$ with the property,
$$
\pi(\theta,1)+\ldots+\pi(\theta,n)=1
$$
which can also be written as $\pi'e=1$. In the same way that we derived $\nabla (\pi' P)$ we can derive
$$
\nabla (\pi' (e \pi'))= \nabla \pi' e\pi' + \pi' \nabla (e\pi') 
$$
Since $e$ is not a function of $\theta$, $\nabla (e\pi')=e\nabla \pi'$ and so,
\begin{equation}
\nabla (\pi' (e \pi'))=\nabla \pi' e\pi' + \pi'e \nabla \pi'=\nabla \pi' e\pi' +  \nabla \pi' \tag{A} 
\end{equation}
However, it is also the case that $\pi'(e\pi')=(\pi' e)\pi'=\pi'$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\nabla (\pi' (e \pi')) = \nabla\pi' \tag{B} 
\end{equation}
From $({\rm A})$ and $({\rm B})$ we  have,
$$
\nabla \pi' e\pi'=0
$$
and so adding this term to $(15)$ does not change the equation.
To understand the part about the inverse of $I - (P-e\pi')$ start with the expression,
$$
(I-A) \sum_{t=0}^T A^t
$$
This is the standard telescoping sum since,
$$
(I-A) \sum_{t=0}^T A^t = \sum_{t=0}^T A^t - \sum_{t=1}^{T+1} A^t
= A^0 - A^{T+1} = I - A^{T+1}  
$$
If $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}A^t =0$ then,
$$
\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty} (I - A^{T+1})=I 
$$
and so,
$$
(I-A) \sum_{t=0}^\infty A^t = I
$$
which means $(I-A)^{-1}=\sum_{t=0}^\infty A^t$. In the paper,
$$
A = P-e\pi'
$$
First note that,
$$
A^2 = (P-e\pi')(P-e\pi')=P^2 - Pe\pi' - e\pi'P + e\pi' e \pi'
$$
Since $\pi' P = \pi'$ and $\pi' e =1$ we have,
$$
A^2 = P^2 - P e \pi'
$$
The transition matrix $P$ has the property $Pe=e$ since the transition probabilities $p_{ij}$ from state $i$ to state $j$,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij}=1
$$
so for $t=2$, $A^2=P^2- e \pi'$. If we assume that for $t-1$, $A^{t-1}=P^{t-1}-e \pi'$ then,
$$
A^{t}=(P-e\pi')(P^{t-1}-e \pi')=P^t - P e \pi' - e \pi' P^{t-1} + e \pi' e \pi'
$$
We have,
$$
\pi' P^{t-1} = (\pi' P) P^{t-2} = \pi' P^{t-2} = \ldots = \pi' P^0 = \pi'  
$$
and so
$$
A^{t}= P^t - e \pi' - e \pi' + e \pi' = P^t - e \pi'
$$
i.e. $(P-e\pi')^t=P^t-e\pi'$. Since $\pi$ is the unique stationary distribution of $P$,
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} P^t = e \pi' 
$$
that is, the transition matrix converges to the stationary distribution $\pi$ and so $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}A^t=0$.

For item (1) regarding the gradient, it seems from the notation that for each element $p_{ij}$ of the original $P$ matrix, a $K \times 1$ column vector is being computed.  Depending on how the result is being used, it seems reasonable to consider it an $n \times n$ matrix of vectors, each element being a vector of dimension $K \times 1.$
For example at the bottom of page 327 of the paper, there is an equation like this:
$$
\nabla \pi' P + \pi' \nabla P = \nabla \pi'
$$
Regarding the second term on the left hand side, I believe $\pi'$ is a $1 \times n$ vector (i.e. the transpose of the $\pi$ vector), so for the matrix product to be defined, $\nabla P$ has to have $n$ rows.
